# What is this back Color translucent background appearing when I click? Is it input element or svg element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, pseudo-class

I don’t know why I am getting this black translucent bg when I click. This happens only on phone not on desktop

[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/136LbOlrNlgUnZXD9pg6wIUp0eDb_b0Mh/view?usp=sharing)

I tried changing the pseudo classes
:active
:focus
:hover but still getting the black translucent bg

btw I am using this in reactjs and took this checkbox input from uiverse [text](https://uiverse.io/catraco/plastic-moth-91)

This is the HTML Code

```
  <input title="like" type="checkbox" class="like">
  <div class="checkmark">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="outline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M17.5,1.917a6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5.5,3.3,6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5.5-3.3A6.8,6.8,0,0,0,0,8.967c0,4.547,4.786,9.513,8.8,12.88a4.974,4.974,0,0,0,6.4,0C19.214,18.48,24,13.514,24,8.967A6.8,6.8,0,0,0,17.5,1.917Zm-3.585,18.4a2.973,2.973,0,0,1-3.83,0C4.947,16.006,2,11.87,2,8.967a4.8,4.8,0,0,1,4.5-5.05A4.8,4.8,0,0,1,11,8.967a1,1,0,0,0,2,0,4.8,4.8,0,0,1,4.5-5.05A4.8,4.8,0,0,1,22,8.967C22,11.87,19.053,16.006,13.915,20.313Z"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="filled" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M17.5,1.917a6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5.5,3.3,6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5.5-3.3A6.8,6.8,0,0,0,0,8.967c0,4.547,4.786,9.513,8.8,12.88a4.974,4.974,0,0,0,6.4,0C19.214,18.48,24,13.514,24,8.967A6.8,6.8,0,0,0,17.5,1.917Z"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg class="celebrate" width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <polygon points="10,10 20,20" class="poly"></polygon>
      <polygon points="10,50 20,50" class="poly"></polygon>
      <polygon points="20,80 30,70" class="poly"></polygon>
      <polygon points="90,10 80,20" class="poly"></polygon>
      <polygon points="90,50 80,50" class="poly"></polygon>
      <polygon points="80,80 70,70" class="poly"></polygon>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.con-like {
  --red: #ee427b;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.con-like .like {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.con-like .checkmark {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.con-like .outline,
.con-like .filled {
  fill: var(--red);
  position: absolute;
}

.con-like .filled {
  animation: kfr-filled 0.5s;
  display: none;
}

.con-like .celebrate {
  position: absolute;
  animation: kfr-celebrate 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: none;
}

.con-like .poly {
  stroke: var(--red);
  fill: var(--red);
}

.con-like .like:checked ~ .checkmark .filled {
  display: block
}

.con-like .like:checked ~ .checkmark .celebrate {
  display: block
}

@keyframes kfr-filled {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes kfr-celebrate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think for you _"back Color translucent background"_ and _"black translucent bg"_ mean the same thing? Could you use the same description in both places please? Are you perhaps referring to the light gray box around the pink heart icon? Also, I would advice against using Google drive to host content for this question. It might stay up long enough for you to get an answer, but if someone else visits your question, 3 years from now, you've likely deleted it. Your question will make no sense without it, especially because your description of the actual problem is quite poor.

Comment: It could be that there are other elements with the same id/class names that are affecting the styling.